# Glossaries package has a conflict with \boldsymbol in headings while hyperref is loaded

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, glossaries, bold

I have encountered an error while trying to add glossaries to a document where I had used `\boldsymbol` in a `\section` command, this error occurs only if the package `hyperref` is loaded.

I hope the proper example is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{report}
%
\linespread{1.1}
%
\usepackage[IL2]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech,british]{babel}
%
\usepackage{hyperref}
%
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
%
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[acronym,nomain]{glossaries}
%
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
%
\newacronym{ads}{AdS}{Anti-de Sitter}
%
\gls{ads}
\section{$\boldsymbol{B}$}
%
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=List of Abbreviations]
%
\end{document}
```

Are there any nice solutions?

---

**Edit**

I have also noticed that when I add a contents line for the list (I do not know if I'm doing it how I should) using `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Abbreviations}` it looks good, but the hyperlink does not work, it jupms to previously created contents line for bibliography, despite the fact, that the list has right page number in contents. Is it also an issue of `glossaries` together with `hyperref`

Comment: With hyperref it's a good idea to wrap math in sections with `texorpdfstring` like so: `\section{\texorpdfstring{$\boldsymbol{B}$}{B}}`

Comment: You're right, it solves the first problem, thanks. May be you should promote this comment to an answer :)

Comment: Your are posting two, basically not connected questions in one. While user `Mass` answered the main question, the other one with wrong hyperlink can most probably cured by using `\phantomsection` right before `\printglossary` and then use `\addcontentsline...` after it, but as far as I can remember, the `glossaries` package has some option to do this automatically.

Comment: The `toc` package option will automatically add the glossary to the table of contents.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to sum up the two solution provided by Mass and Christian Hupfer.

The mathematics (and also the `\boldsymbol` macro) can be in headings, like \section, protected by command `\texorpdfstring{}` which should enclose the math.

Christian contributed with a command `\phantomsection` which should be before `\printglossary` command and helps to make the hyperref in table of contents clickable in the right way.

As he suggested, it is possible to make this automatically. It is done through an option `toc` at loading of the package and you might found useful also a command `toctitle` as option of `\printglossary`, which changes the printed contents name.